# Contracts design pattern in C

Tags: c, design-patterns, code-contracts, design-by-contract

Is there a library/framework/article that describes ways to use contracts in C
I mean code that is more then obvious asserts

for example somting like:
[Programming with Contracts in C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/programming-with-contracts-in-c/184405997)

but for C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do DbC as described here by Samek.

http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Design-by-Contract-for-Embedded-Software